# Regex to find two consecutive Special Characters with no hardcoding

Tags: regex, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to figure a regex in Spark SQL to find if a string has two or more consecutive special characters without any hardcoding. I was able to do it but had hardcoding of regex. This doesn't work out given that the combinations I might have.

`rlike(Column_name,'/.*!!.*|.*@@.*|.*##.*|.*$$.*|.*%%.*|.*\\^\\^.*|.*&&.*|.*\\*\\*.*|.*((.*|.*)).*|.*--.*|.*__.*|.*\\+\\+.*|.*==.*|.*\\{\\{.*|.*[[.*|.*]].*|.*\\}\\}.*|.*\\.*|.*||.*|.*::.*|.*;;.*|.*"".*|.*,,.*|.*<<.*|.*>>.*|.*...*|.*\\?\\?.*|.*\/\/.*|.*- -.*/gm')`

Obviously, this was written when we knew list of consecutive characters that might occur. But we now have a situation where the combinations can be anything. Is there a way to get this dynamic without any hardcoding?

Special Character: Any character apart from a-zA-Z0-9

Comment: Side note: it feels like your current attempt lacking escaping in front of `(` and `[`.

Comment: Would `.*([^a-zA-Z0-9])\1.*` do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

As @markalex suggested in comments, `([^a-zA-Z0-9])\1` will do the job.

**[^a-zA-Z0-9]** -> matches a single special character

**\1** -> matches the same text as the 1st capturing group

Check it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/Zeymrx/1)

Comment: This finds two _identical_ nonalphanumeric characters. Just `[^a-zA-Z0-9][^a-zA-Z0-9]` will find any two adjacent nonalphanumeric characters. `[^a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*[^a-zA-Z0-9]` finds two special characters with zero or more alphanumeric characters between them. And, to quote tchrist, "all characters are special."

Comment: The `+` is actually redundant. If you don't care if there are two or more than two, just finding two is sufficient.

Comment: @tripleee based on the original regex, it seems that OP is looking for identical characters. And thanks for the point regarding the usage of +. updated the answer.

Comment: I'm really not sure if they mean the combinations can be any _permutation_ of nonalphanumeric characters or just any pair of adjacent identical nonalphanumerics.